# XSLT Transformation of an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a beginner in XML + XSLT...

I have an XML file like this :

```
<root>
<NumNum>
   <Ligne>ZZZZZZ</Ligne>
</NumNum>
<Designation>
            <Ligne>Couverture 4 pages</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Format fini : 23.00 x 23.00 cm</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Format ouvert : 46.00 x 23.00 cm</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Papier : COUCHE MODERNE DEMI MAT 300 g/m²</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Impression : Quadri recto/verso</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Eléments fournis : fichiers numériques</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Rainage</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Pelliculage soft touch R°</Ligne>
            <Ligne/>
            <Ligne>Intérieur  28 pages</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Papier : OFFSET 140 g/m²</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Impression : Quadri recto/verso</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Eléments fournis : fichiers numériques</Ligne>
            <Ligne/>
            <Ligne>Façonnage : assemblage + 2 points métal</Ligne>
            <Ligne/>
            <Ligne>Poids théorique d'un exemplaire : 135.42 Gr</Ligne>
            <Ligne/>
            <Ligne>en carton(s)</Ligne>
            <Ligne>Livraison : 75 PARIS</Ligne>
            <Ligne/>
        </Designation>
</root>
```

I need to read the value of the line containing :

```
<Ligne>Impression : Quadri recto/verso</Ligne>
```

But, the position of this line changes randomly... but always inside :

```
<Designation>
</Designation>
```

So, I was thinking of using an XSLT + a regular expression to find any line begining by :

```
"Impression :"
```

I supposed we need to use a loop to gather all lines inside , but any help and/or tips & tricks will be appreciated ;-)

Here is the XSLT I used to pick up values :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="myLines_Ligne"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root/Designation">
        </root/Designation>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:call-template name="GetLine">
                <xsl:with-param name="ListeLigne" select="/root/Designation"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </root/Designation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="GetLine">
        <xsl:param name="ListeLigne"/>
        <myLines_Ligne>
            <xsl:for-each select="$ListeLigne">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Ligne"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </myLines_Ligne>
    </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried to use it for reading the lines I want to extract, but without success... The XSLT returns only the first line "ZZZZZZ" :-(

So, if some of yours can hava a look and help, we will appreciate ;-)

Comment: Please show your actucal XSLT. Currently this does not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the line that starts with `"Impression :"` then why not do exactly that?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="Designation/Ligne[starts-with(., 'Impression :')]"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>Impression : Quadri recto/verso</result>
```

---

Note that this extracts only the first line that meets the criterion. To get all of them, you'd have to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="Designation/Ligne[starts-with(., 'Impression :')]">
            <result>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
```